# Powershell variables not working in IIS appcmd

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to run this:

```
$appcmd = "C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"
$env = "dev1"
$IP = "10.10.10.10"

& $appCMD set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /+"[name='customapp1$env'].bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='$IP:80:customapp1$env.domain.com']" /commit:apphost
```

The problem here is the $IP variable in the appcmd command.  It does indeed modify the binding properties, however when I go to look at it in IIS Manager, it says "The binding information is incorrect" and just shows HTTP with all other field blank.

If I actually type in the IP address as such:

```
& $appCMD set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /+"[name='customapp1$env'].bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='10.10.10.10:80:customapp1$env.domain.com']" /commit:apphost
```

It works just fine (including the other "$env" variable).  How can I get this $IP variable to pass through correctly?

I really appreciate it!

Comment: Try using the the syntax `${IP}` instead.

Comment: You're the man!  Thanks - that worked.  For my own curiosity, why does that work?

Comment: It's because of the following colon. PowerShell uses that to define scope. Using the brackets disassociated the character so it could be evaluated on its own.

Comment: Got it!  Thank you again...

Comment: @DominicBrunetti Matt is correct. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `${IP}` to precisely specify the variable name. `:` is actually considered part of the variable name, which separates a scope or powershell drive from the variable name. So Powershell is interpreting the variable as `$ip:80`, with a scope or drive of `ip` and name of `80`. Since `ip` does not resolve to a scope or drive, you get null for the value.